# Is there a name for turn based combat that uses a speed attribute like ATBs but doesn't involve waiting?

Tags: terminology, combat

I've seen this in a number of games now - for me, I think the first (and one of the better examples) was Blue Dragon - where characters take turns in an order determined by their speed attribute such that a fast character will not only go first, but also take turns more often than a slow character.  This is much like an ATB (Active Time battle) (with Wait=true) BUT the turns still take place immediately after one another (as opposed to each character having a time-bar that runs down in real time).  And in the example of Blue Dragon, a number of tokens appear in a queue to indicate probable turn order (this would fluctuate if a character used a quicker or slower than normal action).

Is there a name for this turn-based-with-time-simulation-combat in games?

Edit: The closest I've come to a satisfactory term for this is a Combatant Cooldown System (https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CombatantCooldownSystem) with a Visual Initiative Queue (https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VisualInitiativeQueue)  I like these but both came from *TV Tropes* and don't appear to be (commonly) in use elsewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t believe there is a commonly-recognized term for what you’re talking about; it falls under the general category of “turn-based” but beyond that hasn’t really reached the point where it’s needed to acquire a unique moniker of its own.

Comment: I can say with some confidence that you're very probably exactly right so I'll accept if/until such a thing comes to exist and be somewhat commonly used and understood.  Personally, I hope this time/speed simulation inclusive type of turn-based game gets it's own sub- term eventually so that I can someday avoid being so long-winded when expressing my game mechanic preferences.

Comment: "No!  Not ATB systems! You know! Those RPGs that sort of simulate time like ATBs but when they pause on your turn and they use some kind of Visual Initiative Queue -which is a sort of 'time bar' that lists the probable turn order in the form of a bunch of face picture icons representing the pieces in play...  You know.  Those!"